# Properties of the universal cover of CW-complexes

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology

Let $Y$ be a CW-complex and $X$ its universal cover. Could you give me a proof (or a referece) for the following fact:

$X$ is contractible $\Leftrightarrow$ $H_i(X)=0$ $\forall i\geq2$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\pi_iY=0$ $\forall i\geq2$.

Comment: This is the Hurewicz theorem and the Whitehead theorem.  The idea is the first non-trivial homology group of a space is the (abelianization of) the first non-trivial homotopy group.  That's Hurewicz.  The Whitehead theorem says that if a map between CW-complexes is an iso on all homotopy groups then it's a homotopy equivalence -- in the case of a CW-complex with all homotopy groups trivial, take a 1-point subcomplex as your other CW complex.  You can find these in any intro alg-top textbook: Spanier, May, Hatcher, Switzer, Whitehead, Kirk&Davis, Harper, and so on.

Comment: For the second implication, use the fact that any map from $S^n \rightarrow Y$ for $n\ge 2$ lifts to a map $S^n \rightarrow X$. So if $X$ has all trivial homotopy groups, then this will be nullhomotopic in $X$, hence nullhomotopic in $Y$.

Comment: You might also find Peter May's paper "On the dual Whitehead Theorems" of interest.

Comment: I can't understand why $\pi_iY=0$ $\forall i\geq2$ implies $X$ contractible. From Whitehead it's clear if I have $\forall i\geq 1$. Other thing that I don't understand is why $H_i(X)=0$ $\forall i\geq2$ implies $X$ contractible (or why it implies the condition on the homotopy groups).